# Why did they use would here?

Tags: grammar, verbs

A 10-day moving average WOULD average out the closing prices for the first 10 days as the first data point. The next data point WOULD drop the earliest price, add the price on day 11 and take the average, and so on as shown below.

Read more: Moving Average (MA) https://www.investopedia.com/terms/m/movingaverage.asp#ixzz59bm4RYnx

Comment: nothing seems wrong with the sentences.

Comment: It's probably the apododis of a remote conditional construction and interpreted as "If P then Q would...

Comment: @BillJ is correct. 'If P' is 'If one decided to adopt the model which is based on a 10-day moving average, [the effect would be to average out ...]'.

Answer (score 1):

They are being safe in their expression. Without looking at the source I can tell there was probably was given some example before this text.

What they are saying is *"in this case with a 10-day moving average the first 10 closing prices will..."*.

So, there is some kind of condition for *the first 10 closing prices to average out to the first data point*. That can be the 10-day moving average **as opposed to** a 5-day moving average. Or for this example the 10-day MA averages out to the first data point, which means there are other examples in which it doesn't.

Comment: I agree with your assessment of the text. The writer probably gave some data as an example and the wrote one or more definitions in the conditional tense, since the reader could in theory “choose” which one to apply to their own data. It’s common for people writing a lot of definitions and examples to stay in the conditional style throughout, even if it isn’t strictly required in every case.

Answer (score -2):

#### Good question.

The word/phrase ahead of "*would*" is actually a noun/noun phrase, and the word/phrase that comes after "*would*" is a verb.

Usage examples:

> **I** (*pronoun*) would **go ahead** (*verb phrase*) and do it.
>
> The old **car** (*noun*) would **tilt over** (*verb phrase*) onto two wheels ever so slightly whenever I tapped the brakes.
>
> I predicted that the **market prices** (*noun phrase*) would **drop** (*verb*) if the company declared bankrupt.

Comment: I would go ahead or I will go ahead? Please explain sir

Comment: this answer looks like it did not answer the question "why".